diff -qr command between local and remote directories
According to this process substitution can be used to do a SIMPLE diff between local and remote machine. However, I want to use the -qr option in the diff command, i.e., it must be recursive and brief (reports only files that differ). If I try to do
diff -qr <(ls -R ~/Documents) <(ssh myusername@192.168.1.150 ls -R /pathinmyremote/My_remote_Documents)

I get Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ which is obviously not what I am looking for. There are suggestions of using rsync with the dry-run option, but that does not include the brief option.
The reason for -qr is that I want to know 1) which files are in my local machine and missing in my remote backup, and 2) which files that have been changed/updated in my local machine with respect to the ones in the backup remote.
Update
The suggestion to use rsync -n -ai --delete ~/Documents myusername@192.168.1.150:/pathinmyremote/My_remote_Documents results in:
<f..tp..... Oneexistingfile.tex
.d..tp..... Oneexisting_directory/
<f.stp..... One_changedfile.tex
<f+++++++++ One_newfile.tex

which is also not right (due to the existing files/directories)

It's unclear why you want to use -q if you also want a  list of differences. That option explicitly turns off the listing of differences.  Also, -r is only useful when comparing directories.  You appear to compare directory listings (output from ls -R), not directories.

Using rsync -n -ai --delete would give you a list of differences. Is that not what the suggestions propose?  (Do not run that without -n!)

The reason for -qr is that I want to know 1) which files are in my local machine and missing in my remote backup, and 2) which files that have been changed/updated in my local machine with respect to the ones in the backup remote. Sorry for the lack of clarity. The -R in the ls is probably wrong (it was just me experimenting on how to achieve the above conditions)

(1) I agree with everything @Kusalananda said.  (2) Why you shouldn’t parse the output of ls(1) is relevant.  (3) If you want to compare your entire Documents tree to your entire My_remote_Documents tree (recursively), then the ls -R is appropriate. (But see point 2.)  (4) It can be useful to respond to comments with more comments. But don’t clarify your question in comments; [edit] it to make it clearer and more complete.  (5) At the risk of repeating point 1, try your command without the -qr. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (6) You may be able to use this approach to get a list of files that are present on one of your machines and missing from the other. Identifying files that exist in both places, but are not identical, will be more difficult.  If Kusalananda’s rsync suggestion doesn’t work, you may be able to devise a partial, clumsy solution with a script. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  One of our mottos is “Unix&Linux Stack Exchange is not a script-writing service.”  If you try to develop a script to do this, and you encounter problems, post a question showing what you have accomplished and describing where you’re stuck.  But note that the Server Fault question you already linked to already covers a lot of territory.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Cheers. Question edited. The rsync command is outputting a lot of files which are not new/changed (example above) and so it seems that I'd have to pipe the output to/and filter it with grep?

@Ajned But the files have changed.  One is completely new on the target side, three of them have changed permissions and timestamps, and one file's size is different.

I agree for the completely new and changed one: I did that on purpose to test the command :-). Timestamp and permissions ought to be the same... Side note: I used to run the diff -qr between my laptop and external HD, but have recently moved all the contents of the external HD to a NAS in which I am trying to run this command. Perhaps that's why the permissions and timestamps have changed? I'll run some other tests and report back.

@Kusalananda Indeed, the issue was related to the moving of files from my HD to the NAS and the command you recommend is analogous to diff -qr. Feel free to answer the question and I'll accept it. Thanks.
